# double slash after redirecting non-www to www

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, http-redirect

I used the following code to redirect non-www traffic to www traffic.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

What happens is that when I look for tupples.com, I instead get www.tupples.com// and the browser displays and error saying that it got too many re-directs.

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Weird. It shouldn't do that.

Try perhaps

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```